# How can we determine whether a REST API is stateless or not?

Tags: rest, web-services, stateless

I have implemented REST APIs (GET and POST), my concern is regarding the stateless part of the REST API standard. This is how the APIs are accessed:
The client logs into the application which is hosted on a web portal. The web portal authorizes the logged in user and adds a identifier in the request.
When a request is made to REST API, a filter implemented within the application checks whether the incoming http request header has an identifier associated with it (added by web portal while authorizing).

If header has identifier associated with it, filter passes the request towards the controller.

It would be appreciable if someone could verify whether this design is in accordance with REST stateless principle.

Answer (score 0):

[Stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3), in the context of REST, has a very specific meaning

> Each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client.

The classic case of session state leaking into HTTP requests is the use of [Cookies](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_3_4_2).

I don't see anything in your description that leads me to think you are using session context here.