# Why are REST APIs considered stateless if PUT commands can update?

Tags: rest

I am a bit confused by the terminology of REST APIs being stateless. For example, if we had a To-Do list API, and one of the endpoints was used to update or delete entries, then each request does *not* happen in isolation.

If I create an entry before someone else queries the total entries, then their response will depend on my response.

But, PUT is seen as a verb of REST APIs. Can someone help me clear my confusion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to understand "RESTful API is stateless"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130036/how-to-understand-restful-api-is-stateless)

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105296/if-rest-applications-are-supposed-to-be-stateless-how-do-you-manage-sessions

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016721/the-meaning-of-stateless-in-rest-and-http

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754919/how-can-we-determine-whether-a-rest-api-is-stateless-or-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stateless means that you store the client state on the client and send it with each request instead of storing it on the server. The latter is the classical server side sessions, where you have a session cookie with the session id and the server stores the session data in the database or file system. This does not scale well for Facebook size applications, that's why they rather send the session data with each request. You can ensure that the session data is not modified by the client if you sign it with a private key stored on the server. So there is signature verification by each request, but still it is less expensive than maintaining session data for more than 1M users in a database and syncing it around the globe with multiple servers to solve the single point of failure problem too. They rather send the session data with each request and if it passes the verification, then the request is handled by any node chosen by the load balancer without touching the database to get session data.

As of the part of the question related to concurrent calls, it can be solved with resource versioning. You can send the actual [ETag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) of the resource and use the [if-match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Match) header with your PUT request so the server will be able to figure out which version you request is based on. If there is a newer version, then the ETag won't match and the server will reject the request. There can be other ways to solve concurrency, it always depends on your application how you handle it.

Comment: This is the part which i have a different opinion.  To me, stateless mean the information to deal with the resources should be self-contained in the request itself, i.e the server is able to base solely on the information in the request to know exactly what to do with this request.    if i am to use the classical server side sessions, and my session contains session id for the purpose of authentication/authorization, what has that to do with the resource handling? The server will still know how to handle the resource purely based on the request information, and not reply on the server session.

Comment: Unfortunately what I say don't correspond to what Roy Fielding indicates in his dissertion "each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client."

Comment: In my opinion,  REST is all about dealing with resources. As long as the information that deals with resources are self-contained in the request, why would anyone care whether I use session to keep track of my login state or not.
That's why i not sure why Roy Fielding care about keeping session state in server or client side.

Comment: @NickWills When you scale up your service keeping session state of millions of users distributed on many servers will be a huge problem. For services with small load it does not really matter.

Comment: @inf3mo Thanks for sharing. I agree with your statement. But my concern is not about whether  using session is good or no good.  My concern is REST specification should not dictate about whether to use session or not session. REST should focus on handling resources. And assuming my services has small load,and i decide to go with using session to keep track of login state, in that case, is my api still considered REST?

Comment: @NickWills Most APIs are not REST, because they don't meet the hypermedia constraint. Not meeting the statelessness constraint is just the same. You can call it whatever you want to, most client developers don't care, they just read the documentation.